# How do I transform an array into the Traditional Form with mathematica?

Tags: mathematica

I am trying to set an expression in Mathematica that uses an array. However it is problematic to typeset this expression and still be able to use it.

Here is my example:

```
data := {{8.2, 123.2}, {8.2, 123.2}, {8.22, 121.8}}
addata := {0.03, 0.3}
Fkt[c_, d_, e_] := Product[c[[dim]]* d[[dim]]* e[[dim]]], {dim, 1, 2}]
Fkt[data, data, addata]
```

Now I want to show the expression only in itself, e.g.:

$Fkt_{c,d, e} := \Pi_{dim=1}^2  c_{dim}*d_{dim}* e_{dim}$

However TraditionalForm does not do this. Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction?

thanks

Comment: "`TraditionalForm[]` does not do this." - it can't. The expression's short; why not type it out yourself? `(esc)prodt(esc)` should generate a product expression whose blanks you can fill in...

Comment: i have shortened the expression a lot already. and i want to use it to eye-proof the expression to make sure there are no mistakes there. You are saying that there is no way to do this in mathematica?

Comment: At least in the form you have produced, the only good way I'm aware of is `TraditionalForm[HoldForm[Subscript[Fkt, c, d, e] := Product[Subscript[c, dim] Subscript[d, dim] Subscript[e, dim], {dim, 1, 2}]]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose an option in the format->cell and cell->convert to as how to display your cells. Besides Shift+Ctrl+T gives the traditional form of a choosen fragment.

There is also `Defer` function, which prints the unevaluated form of an expression:

```
Defer[Product[c[[dim]]*d[[dim]]*e[[dim]], {dim, 1, 2}]]
```

gives

$\prod _{\dim =1}^2 c[[\dim ]] d[[\dim ]] e[[\dim ]]\ $.

Comment: Ah, `Defer[]`. Nice, I'm old-school and have no clue about these newfangled *Mathematica* functions... :)

Comment: thats pretty, cool. It does not solve the problems with the whole array to subscript thing, but its a start.

Comment: Methematica does't regard array's elements as subscripts. If you want subscripts you have to put them directly as in the example of J.M. above. They can be inserted with `Ctrl+_`, say `Fkt`+`(Ctrl+_)`+`c,d,e`+`(Ctrl+Space)` for $Fkt_{c,d,e}$.

Comment: In general, `TraditionalForm[]` stuff is *unsuitable* for computational purposes, @tarrasch. Why not be satisfied with `StandardForm[]`?

Comment: its just that i want to be save. i have a mc-simulation that verifies my code. Yet i will communicate the equation only, not the code. So i want to make sure the equation corresponds to the code. is there a nonstandard package or sth that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would like:

```
Definition[Fkt] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Also, if you would like to change the default TraditionalForm display, for example, displaying `Part` expressions as subscripts, you may use:

```
Unprotect[Part]
Format[Unevaluated@Part[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := Subscript[a, b]
```

Now:

```
Definition[Fkt] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]